# can't complete on fgetcsv in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, fgetcsv

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "abc";
$dbname = "project";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE datapack";
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
     $fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
     echo 'upload file name: '.$fname.' ';
     $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);

     if(strtolower(end($chk_ext)) == "csv")
     {
         $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
         $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
         $head = fgetcsv($handle);
         while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
         {
            $sql= "INSERT into datapack(id,nickname,time,msg) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]')";
            mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            echo "Error: ". $conn->error;
          }
        echo "Success!";                  
     }

     else
     {
         echo "Invalid File";
     }   
}

?>
<h1>Import CSV file</h1>
<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Import File : <input type='file' name='sel_file' size='20'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

After I run the file, i find some problems:

1. The file cannot completely import to mysql (for example, only 600 lines can imports when there is 1000 lines in csv), and everytime i run it, the number of lines importing to mysql is different.
2. It cannot echo success.
3. When echo the error, some lines it tells me incorrect string values.  I thought it was uft-8 problems, but after I just get id and time only, the situation is also the same in point 1

Answer (score 0):

Most importantly, you are not escaping your data. There could be anything in that CSV, breaking that query. Also, you're limiting the line length (so if there are long lines they will not get inserted) and aren't checking for the proper number of columns in the CSV file.  Try changing these things:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "abc";
$dbname = "project";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
    echo "Uploaded file name: $fname";
    $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);

    if(strtolower(end($chk_ext)) === "csv") {
        $sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE datapack";
        $conn->query($sql);
        $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
        $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
        $head = fgetcsv($handle);
        $sql= "INSERT INTO datapack (id, nickname, time, msg) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
            if (count($data) < 4) {
                echo "Error, not 4 columns";
                continue;
            }
            $stmt->bind_param("isss", $data[0], $data[1], $data[2], $data[3]);
            if (!$stmt->execute()) {
                echo "Error: ". $stmt->error;
            } else {
                echo "Success!";
            }
        }
    else {
        echo "Invalid File";
    }
}

?>

<h1>Import CSV file</h1>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Import File : <input type='file' name='sel_file' size='20'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

Note the default HTML behaviour is to post to itself; by needlessly adding `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` you open yourself up to script injection attacks.

Answer (score -1):

executing 1000 query may be too expensive in small servers.

instead you may do bulk insertion .

```
$sql= "INSERT into datapack(id,nickname,time,msg) values";
$sqlArray = array();
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
    $sqlArray[] = "('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]')";
}
$sql .= " " . implode(", ", $sqlArray);

mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
echo "Error: ". $conn->error;
```

---

However , this would be a great chance to begin using [`begin_transaction`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php) for such a case.

> ### mysqli_begin_transaction
>
> Begins a transaction. Requires MySQL 5.6 and above, and the InnoDB
>   engine (it is enabled by default). For additional details about how
>   MySQL transactions work, see »
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/commit.html.